# redis как просмотреть список всех баз?

Tags: redis

как на линуксе через терминал вывести список все баз в Redis, и создать новую?

Answer (score 3):

В Redis базы доступны по целочисленным индексам, по умолчанию 0-15, и их количество определяется ключом `databases` в конфиге (по умолчанию, очевидно, 16). Зная это число, можно сразу сказать, сколько в Redis баз (очевидно) и как называется каждая из них (все названия вида `dbЧИСЛО`). Само число можно получить, сделав `CONFIG GET databases`, а можно, как описано в другом ответе, увидеть сразу список (и некоторую другую информацию), выполнив `INFO keyspace`.

Создать же новые... можно **увеличить количество** баз в Redis, изменив вышеупомянутый ключ `databases` в `redis.conf`. Функционально, в результате увеличения этого числа станут доступны новые, не существовавшие ранее базы.

---

#### Источники:

- [List All Redis Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802726/list-all-redis-databases) — StackOverflow
- [How to create own database in Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621324/how-to-create-own-database-in-redis) — StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте команду `INFO keyspace`, она выводит все базы и кол-во ключей в них.